# How to generate random numbers without duplicates using a loop in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, while-loop

I am writing a random name generator without duplicates. I want to do it without other libaries like **algorithm** because I want to understand how to do that. Is there a way to do that with a loop or a vector?

I thaught of adding the names that have already been to a vector and then check all the elements of the vector with a while loop but I didn't know how I can do that.

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    
using namespace std;

int main() {
 srand((unsigned)time(0));   
    int names = 1;
    int a = 0;
    int x = 0;
    vector <string> vectornames;
    cout << "How many names would you like to add: ";
int amount_of_names;
cin >> amount_of_names;
    while (a < amount_of_names) {

 
cout << "Enter name " << names << ": ";
string name;
cin >> name;
vectornames.push_back(name);
names++;       
a++;   


    
   
       
    }
    while (x < amount_of_names) {
     cout << "\n" << vectornames.at(x);
    x++;   }
    
    cout << "\npress enter to continue: ";
    getch();
    system("cls");
    int z = 0;
while (z < amount_of_names) { 
     
     int random_number = (rand() % amount_of_names);
     if (vectornames.at(random_number) != vectornames.at(z)) {
    cout << "Hello ";
    cout << vectornames.at(z);
    cout << "! You will get " << vectornames.at(random_number) << "\n";
    vectornames.push_back(vectornames.at(random_number));
    
    
    getch();
     
    z++;
}}

    cout << "\n\n";
  

  return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps an `std::unordered_set` for the letters? Generate in a loop until you get the desired length. And please don't use `srand` and `rand`, there are must better [classes available in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: Fill a `vector<int>` with a sequence of numbers like `1, 2, 3, 4 ...` when that is done, `swap` elements at random for a bit. You now have a random sequence of numbers to pick from. `int random_number = vec.back(); vec.pop_back();` (until the `vector` is empty).

Comment: You can use [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and [random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to shuffle a vector of numbers.

Comment: what do you mean by other libraries?

Comment: I mean with the standard librarie and vector with a loop, so without using things from libraries like <algorithm> or others

Comment: @Ususwoa `<algorithm>` and `<random`> and others are part of the Standard Library, just like `<vector>`.

Comment: Oh thanks, then I am asking the question wrong. My question should be how  to can do it with a loop and with vectors.

Comment: Why is `rand()` allowed even though it's often recommended to avoid it and `random` isn't allowed?

Comment: "_how to can do it with a loop and with vectors_" - What is the loop supposed to do? Why do you need a loop? If you have placed the names inside the vector in random order, you can just pick the last name until the vector is empty.

Comment: Please show some examples of what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

The last part has some problems, you select as many names are you have entered, don't know if that was intended lets just say it was. You add the selected names to the same vector, you don't check correctly for duplicates.

```
while (z < amount_of_names) {    <-- same amount as was entered in original loop
  int random_number = (rand() % amount_of_names);
  if (vectornames.at(random_number) != vectornames.at(z)) { <--- doesn't check for duplicates
    cout << "Hello ";
    cout << vectornames.at(z);
    cout << "! You will get " << vectornames.at(random_number) << "\n";
    vectornames.push_back(vectornames.at(random_number)); <---- adding to same vector
    getch();
    z++;
  }
}
```

Lets see what can be done without using algoritmes ... that means we need to implement `std::find` or use some other structure to keep check on what is already selected.

!!!Warning untested code!!!

```
bool Find(const std::string& needle, const std::vector<std::string>& haystack) const {
  for(const auto& straw : haystack) {
    if (straw == needle) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And updated code, which use a different vector to store the used names.

```
std::vector<std::string> used;

while (z < amount_of_names) {
  int random_number = (rand() % amount_of_names);
  
  if (!Find(vectornames.at(random_number), used)) { 
    cout << "Hello ";
    cout << vectornames.at(z);
    cout << "! You will get " << vectornames.at(random_number) << "\n";
    used.push_back(vectornames.at(random_number));
    getch();
    z++;
  }
}
```